# Remove accents in python

Tags: python, string, decode, diacritics

I'm trying to remove all the accents in a string in python using unidecode

and it work pretty well

```
import unidecode

print(unidecode.unidecode('ááíãôç'))
```

it returns

```
aaioac
```

The problem is that i need to keep the 'ç' character

```
aaiaoç
```

Is there some way or some library i can use ? Instead of hard code my way out of this problem ?

Comment: "The problem is that i need to keep the 'ç' character" Why? **What is the rule** that tells you which things to keep and which things to discard? **How will you use** the resulting data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `unidecode` is meant for stripping diacriticals and other things, so that's what it does.

If you need to keep *some, well-known* characters as-is, you'll need to partition the string so those characters *aren't* run through `unidecode`. (Mapping the characters to e.g. Unicode PUA characters and then back won't do – unidecode gobbles them up.)

A suitable way to do that is to come up with a regexp that matches every other character, then use the `re.sub()` function's callback mode to run those runs through `unidecode`:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> import re
>>> keep = 'çÇ'
>>> s = 'ááíãôç hållå! höellô!'
>>> re.sub(f"([^{re.escape(keep)}]+)", lambda m: unidecode.unidecode(m.group(0)), s)
'aaiaoç halla! hoello!'
```